Proving $\sin^2\alpha=\sin^4\phi=\sinh^4\theta$ for real $\alpha$, $\phi$, $\theta$ satisfying $\cosh(\theta+i\phi)=e^{i\alpha}$
If $\cosh(\theta + i \phi) = e^{i \alpha}$ (with $\alpha, \theta, \phi \in \mathbb{R}$), prove that $$\sin^2(\alpha) = \sin^4(\phi) = \sinh^4(\theta)$$
What I've gotten so far:
Since: $$\cosh(\theta + i \phi) = \cosh(\theta)\cos(\phi) + i \sinh(\theta) \sin(\phi)$$ and: $$e^{i \alpha} = \cos(\alpha) + i \sin(\alpha)$$We must have:
$$\cos(\alpha) = \cosh(\theta)\cos(\phi), \\ \sin(\alpha) = \sinh(\theta)\sin(\phi).$$
I've tried rewriting everything in terms of exponentials with Euler's identity, and I get something like:
\begin{align*}
\sin^2(\alpha) &= \left(\frac{e^{i \alpha} - e^{-i \alpha}}{2i} \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{e^{i 2 \alpha} + e^{-i 2 \alpha}}{4} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\left(\cosh^2(\theta + i \phi) + \frac{1}{\cosh^2(\theta + i \phi)} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{22 + 4\left(e^{2\theta+i2\phi} + e^{-2\theta-i2\phi}\right) + e^{4\theta+i4\phi} + e^{-4\theta-i4\phi}}{16\left( 2 + e^{2\theta+i2\phi} + e^{-2\theta-i2\phi} \right)} \\
\end{align*}
But any rewrite of the term $\sin^2(\alpha)$ has both variables $\theta$ and $\phi$ in it, and I can't find a way to get rid of one of them so the necessary equations hold.
Where do I go from here?

You're thinking a little too hard here. :) ... Substitute your expressions for $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\alpha$ into $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$, then rewrite everything in terms of sines (circular and hyperbolic).

You have correctly derived that
$$\cos(\alpha) = \cosh(\theta)\cos(\phi)$$
$$\sin(\alpha) = \sinh(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$
As suggested by Blue in the comments, square the first equation and you get $\cos^{2}(\alpha) = \cosh^{2}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\phi)$. Squaring the second expression yields: $\sin^{2}(\alpha) = \sinh^{2}(\theta)\sin^{2}(\phi)$.
Rewrite the first of these as $1- \sin^{2}(\alpha) = (1+\sinh^{2}(\theta))(1-\sin^{2}(\phi))$. Simplify this, and we conclude that  $\sinh^{2}(\theta) = \sin^{2}(\phi)$. From this it follows that $\sin^{2}(\alpha) = \sinh^{4}(\theta) = \sin^{4}(\phi)$.

Because:$$cos \alpha=\frac {1}{2}(e^{\theta} + e^{- \theta})cos \phi$$ $$sin \alpha=\frac {1}{2}(e^{\theta} - e^{- \theta})sin\phi$$squre sum:$$4=(e^{2\theta}+e^{-2\theta}+2)cos^2\phi+(e^{2\theta}+e^{-2\theta}-2)sin^2\phi$$$$4=e^{2\theta}+e^{-2\theta}+2cos2\phi$$transposition:$$2(1-cos2\phi)=4sinh^2\theta$$then,$$4sin^2\phi=4sinh^2\theta$$now you can get:$$sin^2\alpha=sinh^2\theta sin^2\phi = sin^4\phi = sinh^4\theta $$
